Firebase Hosting "Site Not Found" Error Despite Successful Deployment
I deployed my React app to Firebase Hosting, and the deployment logs indicate success, but accessing the hosting URL shows a "Site Not Found" error. build is performed correctly, as it's running fine on serve -s build.
Here are screenshots of the complete build process and folder structure.


Verified firebase.json:
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Troubleshooting Performed:

Checked the Firebase Console under "Releases" — the latest version is deployed.
Cleared browser cache and tested in incognito mode.
Cleared Firebase Hosting cache by deleting the existing site version and redeploying:

firebase deploy --only hosting


Confirmed the build folder contains all necessary files.


Environment:

React: 18.x
Firebase CLI: 12.x
Hosting URL: https://netflix-gpt-47dd8.web.app

What else should I check to resolve this issue?

This line in your config "public": "build" means that you have to have the web app (with an index.html) in the build directory under your Firebase project directory. From the results you get, it looks like that isn't the case. --- If you can't figure it out, edit your question to show how you build the react app.

@FrankvanPuffelen i updated the question with link to screenshot of build process

Can you show the output from running firebase deploy --only hosting?

@Phil I updated the screenshot of that, please check
